# How javascript code uses a var set in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

In a jsp file, I have this declaration for some url.

```
<c:url value="gotomyweb.do" var="mainLink" scope="session"></c:url>
```

Now I need to use that var "mainLink" in some javascript in the same page.

```
<html:link href="#" onclick="showMainLink()" > Go to web </html:link> 

<script>
function showMainLink() {
    var url="${mainLink}";
    navigating(url);
}
</script>
```

The problem is the var "url" in js is not resovled. How can I get the var "mainLink"?

Another way I can think of is to include var "mainLink" as a parameter like this

```
<html:link href="#" onclick="showMainLink('${mainLink}')" > Go to web </html:link> 

<script>
function showMainLink(url) {
    navigating(url);
}
</script>
```

Still I got some syntax error. Please help.

Comment: Whaaatttt are you doing??

Comment: @Akshay Khandelwal It might seems ridiculous but I have good reason to use some client side code to take care of some var set up in jsp.  I put some dummy code in my question just for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to do it without the var?

```
<html:link href="#" onclick="showMainLink()" > Go to web </html:link> 

<script>
function showMainLink() {
    var url="gotomyweb.do";
    navigating(url);
}
</script>
```

If not you should use:

```
<html:link href="#" onclick="showMainLink()" > Go to web </html:link> 

<script>
function showMainLink() {
    var url="<c:out value="${mainLink}" />";
    navigating(url);
}
</script>
```

Info : http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-access-a-jstl-variable-in-a-scriptlet.html

Comment: The url var is actually set up dynamically. So I have to use a var. And I think c:out is understood only to server not to browser. But I will try that for sue.

Comment: Ah i toughed the <script> was inline in a jsp file so that would be run on the server. If not you have to put the <c:out in the showMainLink(<c:out .. ) and use it as a parameter in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to use Javascript? Try it this way:

```
<c:url value="gotomyweb.do" var="mainLink" scope="session"></c:url>
<a href="${mainLink}" >Go to web</a>
```

Comment: I have some more process to do in the js. Just for simplicity, I put some dummy code in my question. I do need to use the js code.

Comment: Well, I personally avoid js as far as I can, simply for compatibility reasons (if someone has it deactivated) plus you can do the same and better with a Java backend. Hmm, I believe I can't help you with this as long as I didn't try myself, sorry.